# Making a request with permanent token within the SOAP header

Tags: soap-api, java

I need to get some info via SOAP calls and I stick with one error. Right now I need to support two ways of sending SOAP calls:

1. making a call with username-password params
2. making a request with permanent token within the SOAP header (without providing user name and password)

The first case is working fine. Here is a sample:

```
ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
partnerConfig.setPassword(password);
partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint("https://" + instanceUri + "/services/Soap/u/27.0");
partnerConfig.setRestEndpoint("https://" + instanceUri + "/services/data/v27.0");
partnerConfig.setPrettyPrintXml(true);
PartnerConnection partnerConnection = new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
DescribeGlobalResult global = partnerConnection.describeGlobal();
```

**global** object is returned successfully.

Then I tried to do this via SOAP headers. Here is my code:

```
ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
partnerConfig.setServiceEndpoint("https://" + instanceUri + "/services/Soap/u/27.0");
partnerConfig.setSessionId(soapToken);
partnerConfig.setManualLogin(true);//to prevent login() for partnerConnection 
partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint("https://" + instanceUri + "/services/Soap/u/27.0");
partnerConfig.setRestEndpoint("https://" + instanceUri + "/services/data/v27.0");
partnerConfig.setPrettyPrintXml(true);
PartnerConnection partnerConnection = new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
partnerConnection.setCallOptions(soapToken, null);
DescribeGlobalResult global = partnerConnection.describeGlobal();
```

in this case I'm getting

```
UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_SESSION_ID' exceptionMessage='Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session'
```

error after partnerConnection.describeGlobal();

Can someone help me in this question? Maybe I missed something.

Regards, Eugene

Comment: The session id is what you get back from salesforce which lets you connect without specifying the username and password. You appear to be setting it partnerConfig.setSessionId(soapToken); but where is the value of soapToken being populated in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If by permanent token you mean an OAUth refresh token, then you can not make API calls directly with the refresh token, instead you use the refresh token to get a new access token an use that to call the API (passing the access token in the same way you'd pass a sessionId)

Comment: Thank. I will try to get more details about token that I have. Any way thank for your help!